# Call jquery dialog box in master page

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I use MVCHaack.ajax to call a controller function by javascript. Before call the function I show a jquery dialog box. When I use this in my views, everything is perfect but in master pages when I call, dialog box display as a block of text and not like a dialog. this is my master page code :

```
            <script src="/json/RequestVIP?json"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/RequestVIP.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#vipdel').click(function () {
            $("#messagec").replaceWith("<span id=messagec>آیا از حذف عضویت ویژه مطمئن هستید؟</span>");
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                buttons: {
                    "بلی": function () {
                        $mvc.RequestVIP.Delete({ customerId: $("#hdnId").val() }).success(function (data) {
                            $("#messagec").replaceWith("<span id=messagec>" + data.message + "</span>");
                            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                                buttons: {

                                    "تایید": function () {
                                        $(this).dialog("close");
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
                        });
                    },
                    "خیر": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");

            // alert(data.message);

        });
    });
</script>






 <div class="section">
                                <h2 class="title">• عضویت ویژه</h2>
                                            @Html.Hidden("hdnId", @User.Identity.Name.Trim())
                                <button style="width:150px;vertical-align:middle" id="vipreq"><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/join.png")"/>درخواست عضویت ویژه</button><br/>
                                <button style="width:150px;vertical-align:middle" id="vipdel"><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/deljoin.png")"/>حذف عضویت ویژه</button><br/>
                                <button style="width:150px;vertical-align:middle" id="viprev"><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/rejoin.png")"/>تمدید عضویت ویژه</button><br/>
                            </div>


   <div id="dialog-confirm" title="عضویت ویژه">
        <p>
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="font-family: Tahoma; float: right; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;">
            </span><span id="messagec"></span>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you have `jquery.ui` script and stylesheet in your layout page included?

Comment: Yes. I include both               <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: You can check with a browser inspector if they actually are loaded and applied to the dialog element.

Comment: It's solved. I change the line position of these <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>. I putted them before the jquery definition. I put them after jquery definition and everything is ok.  Thank you.

Comment: Changed to what? Maybe it will help somebody else.